# Обфускация java и рекурсия

Tags: java, рекурсия, обфускация

В своём проекте пришёл к необходимости использования рекурсии.В дальнейшем для защиты приложения хочу использовать обфускация. Читал что код с рекурсией нельзя обфускировать. Может кто сказать, почему? Или скажите, пожалуйста, где почитать про это.

Comment: А там, где читали, не объясняли почему?

Comment: @rjhdby на одном из форумов видел, но сообщения были уже старыми

Comment: возмите и проверьте. и сразу поймете, работает ваш обфускатор с рекурсией или нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Теоретически такое может происходить, потому что обычно обфускаторы работают по 2-м направлениям:

1. Обфускация данных: переименование переменных, классов, убирание отладочной информации
2. Обфускация логики выполнения: обычно замена инструкций `if` на `do-while` или наоборот, есть фокусы/покусы с `try-catch` и т.д.

Рекурсия это специальный вид логики выполнения и я склонен верить, что при такой глубинной обфускации рекурсия может стать проблемой.

Однако не все так плохо. Все обфускаторы имеют настроечные параметры, которыми можно задавать какие классы/методы можно обфусцировать, а какие точно нельзя. Так что пишите, а потом с обфускацией решите отдельно.